# Send user credentials in aiohttp request

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, aiohttp, http-authentication

I can't find a way to send user credentials with aiohttp. I want similar behavior to cURL's

```
curl --user "USER:PASSWORD"
```

but in aiohttp. On the reference doc I can't find this option, I can find query parameters, headers, body, but not user credentials.

I'm using aiohttp instead of curl for its asynchronous behavior.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is the same as using basic authentication.

So to use it in `aiohttp`, you could use `aiohttp.BasicAuth`. Somehow like:

```
async with client.get(url, auth=aiohttp.BasicAuth(user, password)) as resp:
    assert resp.status == 200
    print(await resp.text())
```

Comment: Yes, if you use it with `ClientSession`, then all requests sent by this client will have this `BasicAuth`. And you also can overwrite it with my answer.