# aiohttp unclosed client session

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Relating to my question posted earlier [how to post aiohttp authenticated request? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76187721/how-to-post-aiohttp-authenticated-request) which was answered in [Send user credentials in aiohttp request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803114/send-user-credentials-in-aiohttp-request), I modified the code to below and managed to get the result from `get_all_balances()`, however I would have the error below prior to getting the result:

> Unclosed client session
> client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000019AD3E12790>
> Unclosed connector
> connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x0000019AD3E09470>, 613500.125)]']
> connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x0000019AD34A93D0>

As far as I can see, the function is called with `async with` and the result is with `await`, my understanding is that the connection would be closed upon the result, so why is it that it's giving me an unclosed client session error?

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json


base_url = 'https://api.luno.com'
lapikey = ''
lapisecret = ''


async def do(method, path, req=None, auth=False):
    args = {}
    params = None
    if req:
        try:
            params = json.loads(json.dumps(req))
        except Exception:
            params = None
    if params:
        args = dict(params=params)
    url = make_url(path, params)
    if auth:
        args['auth'] = aiohttp.BasicAuth(lapikey, lapisecret)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession().request(method, url, **args) as res:
        try:
            return await res.json()
        except Exception as e:
            return e

def make_url(path, params):
    if params:
        for k, v in params.items():
            path = path.replace('{' + k + '}', str(v))
    return base_url + '/' + path.lstrip('/')

async def get_all_balances():
    return await do('GET', '/api/1/balance', auth=True)


print(asyncio.run(get_all_balances()))
```

I have read other similar questions on aiohttp unclosed client session, as far as I can tell my code has already implemented all the requisite `async with` and `await` keywords to properly close the client session after the request, what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to first make an aiohttp `Session()` and afterwards do a request:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json


base_url = 'https://api.luno.com'
lapikey = ''
lapisecret = ''


async def do(method, path, req=None, auth=False):
    args = {}
    params = None
    if req:
        try:
            params = json.loads(json.dumps(req))
        except Exception:
            params = None
    if params:
        args = dict(params=params)
    url = make_url(path, params)
    if auth:
        args['auth'] = aiohttp.BasicAuth(lapikey, lapisecret)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:                # <--- create session here
        async with session.request(method, url, **args) as res:   # <-- and then do a request
            try:
                return await res.json()
            except Exception as e:
                return e

def make_url(path, params):
    if params:
        for k, v in params.items():
            path = path.replace('{' + k + '}', str(v))
    return base_url + '/' + path.lstrip('/')

async def get_all_balances():
    return await do('GET', '/api/1/balance', auth=True)


print(asyncio.run(get_all_balances()))
```

Comment: thanks that worked, though why is that necessary to properly close a session?